# APi for getting Active VMs from Softlayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to have list of active VMs from Softlayer. As I need to
    As I need to compare that list with my data base list of Vms. 
    Kindly make a needful favour. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an objectMask to retrieve certain attributes that you need from the method that you’re using. Like this:

```
https://$username:$apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,status[name]]
```

Method: GET

Furthermore, you can use an objectFilter to obtain just the matches that you want. For example:

```
https://$username:$apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,status[name]]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"status":{"name":{"operation":"Active"}}}}
```

Method: GET

Related documentation:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters